# Can I swap sabji Masala for Tandoori Masala in this recipe?

Tags: indian-cuisine

thought I'd ask more experienced cooks on their advice for this recipe. Found it a while back on a Suhana sabji masala box. I made it and turned out fantastic. I want to make it again but I have all but the sabji masala and instead have tandoori masala.  Is it possible to switch? I understand it would taste different but I'm wondering how different.

```
1 potato diced
2 medium Onions-chopped 
1/2 cup of cauliflower florets
1 medium bell pepper 
1 tbsp sabji masala < *
1/2 tbsp chili powder 
1/4 tumeric powder 
1/2 cup of water
3 tbsp of oil
```

Comment: You need to compare the ingredients between sabji masala and tandoori masala. I won't recommend substituting. Tandoori masala will have quit a bit of ginger and garlic to combat the game-y taste of meat. Sabji masala is more herbs,less in ginger and garlic .

Answer (score 5):

Spice mixes tend to vary quite a lot from recipe to recipe. If you go to an Indian shop and compare a few brands of tandoori masala (or search online for different recipes) you'll probably notice that there are quite large differences in both the quantity and types of spices used. I've tried a few packaged tandoori masala and have tried a few recipes and they can definitely vary quite a bit in flavour. I'm sure the same is true of the sabji masala.

In all likelihood, most of the spices would be present in both mixes. Without knowing the specific spices used in your mixes, however, it's hard to say exactly what would be different. Some spices are quite distinctive - i.e. the sabji masala might have fenugreek leaves (kasoori methi) which have a pronounced flavour, but then again, some tandoori masalas also include it.

Whatever spices used, I think the tandoori masala will work fine in the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the ingredients you can use any masala.

Essential spices in Indian cooking are cinnamon, coriander, cardamom, mace, peppercorn, and black cardamom. All these spices are dry roasted and then ground to powder to create the "*sabzi masala*" as they label it in marketing world, though there is nothing specific called "sabzi masala".

On the other hand, tandoori masala is something very much different. It's for use as a barbeque marinade. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandoori_masala
It has many more to it then sabzi masala which may make it little too much for the potato recipe as potato absorbs too much too quickly

Comment: I'm a bit confused... you first say that you can use any masala but then say that tandoori masala is very different... which is it?

Comment: it depends on the ingredients can you post the ingredients of tandoori masala with you

Comment: You would have to ask the person who asked the question. You should be able to comment on the question directly.